# replace nested html elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

I hava a huge dom element which i should replace some nested list html element in it.
I also tried to remove the old nested element and add the new nested element but this also wasnt success.

```
const someNewNestedListElement = someNestedListElement
const replacedElement= elementToBeReplaced.replaceChild(someNewNestedListElement , elementToBeReplaced.querySelector(".someOldNestedListElement");
```

The dummy code above runs into an error. Can someone help me out here?
Im pretty new to javascript and dom manipulation so i maybe need some tricks here.

Comment: What error did your code run into?

Comment: No specific error it simply didnt work. My guess was, that i cant use the querySelector in my replaceChild function or maybe i cant replace nested childs (or childs with childs like the ul list with some li elements i want to replace)

Comment: you could simply do `oldListelement..replaceWith(newListElement)`. But you have to create the new list element before that. `const someNewNestedListElement = someNestedListElement` is as if you renamed your variable. doesn't change the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this

```js
const h2 = document.querySelector("h2"),
      button= document.querySelector("button"),
      newItem = document.createElement('p');

newItem.innerText = "replaced text";

button.onclick = function() {
try {
  h2.parentNode.replaceChild(newItem, h2);
  }
catch {
  console.log("already replaced");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <h1>Header1</h1>
  <div >
    <h2>Header2</h2>
  </div>
  <p>some dummy text</p>
  
  <button>replace header2</button>
</div>
```